# Página HTML com margens ruins

Tags: html, css

Eu estou tentando colocar um slideshow na minha página, mas por alguma razão, as imagens têm algum tipo de margem esquerda que não abrange a totalidade da página.

Aqui está a imagem: [image: captura de tela da página]

Aqui está o HTML:

```html
<xmp><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en">
        <meta name="author" content="João Paixão">
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
        <meta name="description" content="InfoCE, Information of Criptocurrency & Entertainment. You'll find the information you're looking for here">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>InfoCE</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="corpo.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="cabecalho.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="icon" href="images" type="image/icon">
    </head>
    <body>
<header>
             <ul>
                <li class="home"><a href="indexpt.htm">Ínicio</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropbtn">Criptomoedas</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="wicriptopt.htm">O que são criptomoedas?</a>
                            <a href="mingpt.htm">Mineração</a>
                            <a href="fctpt.htm">Faucets</a>
                            <a href="wlltpt.htm">Carteiras</a>
                        </div>
               </li>
               <li class="dropdown">
                   <a>Entretenimento</a>
                       <div class="dropdown-content">
                           <a href="filmspt.htm">Filmes</a>
                           <a href="srispt.htm">Séries</a>
                           <a href="animespt.htm">Animes</a>
                       </div>
               </li>
               </ul>
               <div id="logosite">
                    <a href="indexpt.htm"><img src="image/logosite.png" width="100" height="51.5"></a>
               </div>
               <div id="top">
                   <li><a href="ctcuspt.htm">Contacte-nos</a></li>
                <img src="image/pt-icon.png" alt="icon-pt" width="25px" height="25px" style="margin-top:12px;margin-left:0px;">
                   <select onchange="location = this.value;">
                       <option value="indexpt.htm">Português</option>
                        <option value="indexen.htm">English</option>
                   </select> 
                </div>
       </header>
       <section>
       <div class="displayimg">
       <div class="w3-content" style="">
  <img class="mySlides" src="image/cryptocurrenciesalternative.jpg">
  <img class="mySlides" src="image/imgindexbtc.jpg">
  <img class="mySlides" src="image/bitcoin_1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="w3-center">
  <div class="w3-section">
    <button class="w3-btn" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">❮ Prev</button>
    <button class="w3-btn" onclick="plusDivs(1)">Next ❯</button>
  </div>
  <button class="w3-btn demo" onclick="currentDiv(1)">1</button> 
  <button class="w3-btn demo" onclick="currentDiv(2)">2</button> 
  <button class="w3-btn demo" onclick="currentDiv(3)">3</button> 
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
     dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-red", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-red";
}
</script>
</div>
       </section>
       <footer>
           <hr>
           InfoCE.com &copy; 2017 Todos os direitos reservados &#124; <a href="pdp.htm" target=_blank >Política de Privacidade</a>
       </footer>
   </body>
</html></xmp>
```

E aqui vai o CSS:

```css
body{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
section{
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: red;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 20px 20px 0px 30px;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
section a:link{
    color: darkgreen;
    background-color:transparent;
    text-decoration:none;
}
section a:visited{
    color: darkgreen;
    background-color:transparent;
    text-decoration:none;
}
section a:hover{
    color: blue;
    background-color:transparent;
    text-decoration:none;
}
section a:active{
    color: darkorchid;
    background-color:transparent;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.cts{
    margin-left: 760px;
}
select{
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    width: 20px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: darkorange;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: -10px;
}
#top li{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}
li {
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: -2px;

}
li.home {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: dodgerblue;
color: white;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1020px){
    ul.topnav li.right, 
    ul.topnav li {float: none;}
}
header{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#top{
    margin-top: -71px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    float: right;
}
#top select{
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#logosite {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: -71px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: 750px;
}
header #logosite{
    float: left;
}
afinal nao kkk
footer{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: aqua;
}
footer a:link{
    color: darkgreen;
    background-color:transparent;
    text-decoration:none;
}
footer a:visited{
    color: darkgreen;
    background-color:transparent;
    text-decoration:none;
}
footer a:hover{
    color: blue;
    background-color:transparent;
    text-decoration:none;
}
footer a:active{
    color: darkorchid;
    background-color:transparent;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: Hey dude, this is stackoverflow in portuguese, post your question here http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: O curioso é que a página dele está em português :)

Comment: O que seria o `afinal nao kkk` perdido no meio do CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode botar na classe mySlides:

```
.mySlides {
    margin: auto;
}
```

Isto centralizaria as imagens, já que elas tem `display: block;`

Agora, se quiser centralizar todo o conteúdo, eu recomendaria estas mudanças:

```
.displayimg {
    text-align: center;
}
.w3-content {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Isso tudo seria uma sugestão bem simples sem maiores conhecimentos da sua página que me parece estar em Wordpress. Mas fica lançada a ideia.